# Can I use Mojo.Controller.showAlertDialog within PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, mojo

This afternoon I'm trying PhoneGap 1.5, and I cannot use `navigator.notification.alert("Hello", function() {}, "OK")` but `navigator.notification.alert("Hello")` works. I checked phonegap.js and did find the definition that `Notification.prototype.alert = function(message, response, icon) {...};`. So, what's wrong?
Actually I just want to see whether can I use such a thing like `Mojo.Controller.showAlertDialog` which shows a modal dialog so that users can have a choice what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using JQuery Mobile along with the HTML in PhoneGap?

The latest version of JQM has a lot of these kind of things covered, plus the use of JQuery functions for covering things like AJAX, buttons & other